# align-content not centering the div

Tags: html, css

I want to center the black div using the align-content center, but it is not getting centered.

```css
.container{
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;

    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content:center;
}

.flex{
    display: flex;
    width:30%;
    height:30px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="flex"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

https://ibb.co/fXGb6j2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned the rules wrong. `.container` needs to have `display: flex;` not the child of the container. And it has to be `justify-content: center;` not `align-content: center;`.

- `justify-content: center;` causes the horizontal center
- `align-items: center;` causes the vertical center

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.flex {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex">I am centered!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Niklas E. Can i center it horizontally also without using margin 0 auto.

Comment: I updated my answer. If that was helpful and you used this answer to solve your problem, it would be nice if you mark that answer as accepted. Of cause only if you want.